# Vuejs vue-truncate-filter package showing ReferenceError

Tags: vuejs2

I've installed **npm install vue-truncate-filter --save** for VueJs to cut extra strings for UI purpose. According to package documentation I've implemented the package step by step in my application but it's showing me error. I'm writing same steps here please guide me where I'm wrong:

1- Install vue-trauncate-filter package using npm

```
npm install vue-truncate-filter --save
```

2- include vue-trancate-filter in application

```
var VueTruncate = require('./node_modules/vue-truncate-filter');
Vue.use(VueTruncate)
```

3- Used it in my template using this code

```
{{ text | truncate 100 '....' }}
```

after implementation when I hit the url in browser it showing following error
**ReferenceError: require is not defined**

I tried to find solution but I'm unable to solve the issue. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: I'm using Vuejs2 for my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is just include the file like traditional javascript in your html file. Don't add require i'm placing path what I understand from your code. Please make it according to your directory if path is wrong

```
<script src="./node_modules/vue-truncate-filter/vue-truncate.js"></script>
```

After including this file just remove code bellow from your code

```
var VueTruncate = require('./node_modules/vue-truncate-filter');
Vue.use(VueTruncate)
```

The code you are using to hide extra string is only for vuejs 1 not for vuejs 2 so please replace your code

```
{{ text | truncate 100 '....' }}
```

with this code, it's for vuejs 2

```
{{ text | truncate(100)}}
```

hopefully it will work.

Comment: Is there any other way also?

Comment: That may be using require but I implemented it by including the file, it worked for me